# How to write Generics for java.lang.Number in JDK 1.8

Tags: java, generics, numbers

I have codes like these, which I like to make it works for byte, short, int, long, float and double:

```
// IF I past in List<Long> it should return List<Long>.
public static <T extends Number> List<T> noneNegativeInts(List<T> numbers) {
        List<T> values = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T num : numbers) {
            values.add((T) Math.abs(num.doubleValue())); // !! Compiler error here.
        }
        return values;
    }
```

---

### Also, this code below:

```
public static <T extends Number> T abs(T number) {
    if(number instanceof Double){
        Double val=number.doubleValue();
        return (T)(val <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - val : val;
    }
    if(number instanceof Float){
        Float val=number.floatValue();
        return (T)(val <= 0.0F) ? 0.0F - val : val;
    }
}
```

---

How should these code be changed??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no generic `Math.abs` function. `Math.abs` expects a specific type, e.g. `double`, `int`, etc. Therefore, you're forced to convert your generic type to a specific type, like `double`, and once you've made that conversion you cannot make it generic again.

Thus what you could do is follow the same pattern as the [`Number` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) and create individual methods for each numeric type. For example:

```
public static <T extends Number> List<Integer> nonNegativeInts(List<T> numbers) {
    // ...
}

public static <T extends Number> List<Double> nonNegativeDoubles(List<T> numbers) {
    // ...
}

// etc.
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no generic Math.abs function. <<<
Agreed. How to code one for myself?

Comment: @MatthewOng You cannot code a generic `abs`, because the generic type will always have to be converted to a concrete type before calculating the absolute value, meaning that the return type will always be a specific type. This is why the `Math` library has 4 separate functions for `abs` rather than one generic one. I feel your pain because I ran into this same issue recently.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [upper bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class A {
    public static List<? extends Number> noneNegativeInts(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
        List<Number> values = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Number num : numbers) {
            values.add(Math.abs(num.doubleValue()));
        }
        return values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(noneNegativeInts(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2,3,4,5,-1})));
        System.out.println(noneNegativeInts(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {2.,3.,4.,5.,-1.})));
        System.out.println(noneNegativeInts(Arrays.asList(new Byte[] {2,3,4,5,-1})));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Upper bounded wildcards are useful when you want to make a method that can work across multiple Collection types whose parametrized types are related by a superclass, e.g.: `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>` and so on. These types have no direct superclass, except for with wildcards, which let you express a "pseudo-superclass" to all these Collection types based on the superclass of their parametrized types, `Number`. Then your methods will work with any class that exists under the bound you specified.

Comment: I tried making changes to abs(T number), but does not work:
--------------------------
    public static <? extends Number> abs(<? extends Number> number) {
        if(number instanceof Double){
            Double val=number.doubleValue();
            return (Number)(val <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - val : val;
        }
        if(number instanceof Float){
            Float val=number.floatValue();
            return (?)(val <= 0.0F) ? 0.0F - val : val;
        }
    }
---------------------

Comment: You use the grave symbols like this: ` ` and put the code inside them. However, block level formatting (with indents and such) cannot be done in comments.

Comment: But anyways, you need `(List<? extends Number> numbers)` as your method parameter...the example in my code is runnable so you should be able to get it integrated into your code.

Comment: This function returns `List<Double>`. @MatthewOng specified that "IF I past in List<Long> it should return List<Long>"

Comment: @bmat Ah I see....well I think it's possible to do that with some reflection...but that's not a topic I'm very strong in unfortunately. If it's not possible then it will have to be done the tedious way, coding multiple methods for each type.